Trying to merge multiple folders - I messed up
I wanted to merge multiple folders into one, so I used this command in terminal:
cd containing_folder
mv */* .

Well that didn't really go as planned and resulted in lots of folders being moved to my main User folder - screenshots included.
I think I messed up lots of things, please help! Is there a way to reverse this and get things back into place?
Note to self - don't play with Terminal, you're a noob!




Is there a way to reverse this and get things back into place?

No, not without a load of manual copying (dragging and dropping) of the folders back to their rightful place(s).
You can't just "undo" a mv (or any Terminal command, for that matter) unless you have a backup, Time Machine or otherwise.
You do have a backup, don't you?

If you do not have a backup, then you need to drag everything back to where they were.
If this mistaken mv was made upon a fresh install, and you either don't have any documents, or you have already made a copy of your documents (on to another disk), then it is probably better (i.e. safer) to just do a clean reinstall... and then move your documents back.
Note: If you are sure that that mv was contained within your home directory (rather than at root (/) level), then you could just delete that particular user and their home directory, and create a new user instead.
However, if you aren't sure where you were, i.e. what your pwd was, and that you may have caused file displacement within the OS itself, then a re-install is advisable.

No (I know!)  So I totally deserve this. I rely on iCloud to backup my Documents, Downloads and Desktop folders, and I foolishly thought that would be enough... So I guess I need to Google where each folder goes and manually drag it back there, correct? This is a nightmare, oh well...

Yes, I agree! It's a couple months old MacBook, I think it would be less hassle to just copy the documents and do a clean install. And I'll start doing a proper backup going forward! Thank you so much for your help, this was really stressful, so the advice was super welcome!

btw, iCloud is not a backup solution, it is a synchronisation solution. If you delete a file on one machine, it will be deleted on all others too.

The command mv */* . will move anything whose path includes [some characters] / [some characters] (where / is a directory 'level'), and move them to the current directory.
In other words, you've moved the subfolders from each of the main folders in your user account to your user home.
The current directory appears to have been the user home ~/ , and not containing_folder, which doesn't seem to be in the list.
The command cd containing_folder will only work, if containing_folder is a subfolder of the current location. If not, you should get an error.
Most of those have come from your Library, but some (e.g. iTunes, TV), have come from Music.
This is of course one of the many reasons that people have backups. iCloud is not a backup.

Understood, this was so stupid of me to do without understanding what I'm actually doing... Does it make sense to just start over, create a new User and delete this one? Or did I really mess it up well and need to do a clean OS install?

@mixyy There are very few reasons why you should ever need to reinstall the OS. All you have done is messed up your user account, which is an entirely separate area from the OS.
